# FadeIn not waiting the end of the animation

Tags: jquery

JQuery's manual about the FadeIn function :

```
$( "#book" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
});
```

Yet on my page, the code inside my fadeIn function won't be triggered once "animation complete" but immediately, I don't understand why.

```
$( "#contact-callback" ).fadeIn( 5000, function() {
    $("#callback-message").fadeIn(150);
    $("##callback-dismiss").fadeIn(150);
    $("#tab-contact button .fa").removeClass('fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin').addClass('fa-paper-plane');
    $('#tab-contact #contact-form')[0].reset();
});
```

I believe I followed the exact model described on the manual but it looks I must be wrong somewhere, why won't the code inside my fadeIn function wait for the animation to be completed ?

Comment: Which animation are you saying isn't complete before the next one runs? Are you talking about `#contact-callback` or the 2 `$.fadeIn()`'s nested in the callback? Btw, you have a typo `##callback-dismiss` - and you should post the relevant HTML, too, creating a verifiable demo for us http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Seems to work in a small test case with the first element: https://jsfiddle.net/L649z23k/. Which part are you referring to? Is the `contact-callback` element set to `display: none` initially?

Comment: Hello, well according to the manual I think everything inside the main FadeIn function (#contact-callback) is supposed to be triggered only when the animation is complete right ? Thanks for the typo, I will add a demo right away !

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but you have a double `##` in `$("##callback-dismiss").fadeIn(150);`

Comment: Yes the 3 elements I fade are intially set on display: none. After fixing my type (thanks !) it looks like only the reset() is still triggering at the start of the fadeIn animation

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, your problem is probably somewhere else in your code. See this example:

```js
$("#contact-callback").fadeIn(2000, function() {
  console.log("finished");
});
```

```css
#contact-callback {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contact-callback" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed one problem was a typo mistake, but the reset() function still seems to start early, after a quick search it seems not being isolated to me, I may try an alternative to reset() and see how it goes !